# $this->addElement('type', 'id', array('specs')) VS new Zend_Form_Element_Type('id');

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

What are the Pro's and Con's of:

```
$this->addElement('type', 'id', array('specs'))
```

vs

```
new Zend_Form_Element_Type('id');
```

I think the second is preferable because more readable and offers auto-completion.

Comment: You named it, the first one will have additional chackups and my guess is, that it is slower than the direct alternative. Personally i choose the second option, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Zend Framework provides this flexibility so that you can tailor the API to your needs. So, the answer is "it depends"...

In my opinion, the array interface could be prefereable if you get the form elements data from a configuration file (for instance, you might need to modify often the form elements during development or production of your application), while the object creation interface looks "cleaner" and is less error prone (you can get auto completion from your IDE, as you say).

Hope that helps,